# How can i get a pull_request_template.md to run when a pull request is made and when the pull_request_template.md is located in a git submodule

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, pull-request

Kia Ora all,

#this is my first ever poast after using StackOverflow so many times.
#im wokring in Azure devops pipelines, Visual studio, using git.

Im working on a project with many repositories,
one of those repositories will house my pull_request_template.md

and each other repository will have the "pull_request_template.md repository" as a submodule.

so i can edit the pull_request_template.md and the other repositories should inherit the changes.

i know that git will automatically run a pull_request_template.md file if the name pull_request_template.md is in the root... but what about if pull_request_template.md is in a git submodule

HOW can I get pull_request_template.md to run on a Pull request when it is located in a submodule of the repo being pulled.

Edit: as mentioned by Bright Ran-MSFT i cannot find the ability in ADO to do this, however i am trying to apply Hooks to get git to get PULL_REQUEST_FILE from the submodule. will update if this works.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, on the Pull Request page, there is no method to let the submodule files also be listed.

However, when the Pull Request triggers a build pipeline, on the [checkout task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines), you can set to check out the submodules together.